# how do you access bem style selectors dynamically using css modules?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-modules, css-loader

for example I have a following selector in App.module.css file:

> `.Column--active`

and I would like to access this selector from App.js file in React using css modules. First I import all selectors from css file as `import styles from './App.module.css'`, however when I try to apply styles on a given div as following `<div className={styles.Column--active}`> I get an error at the very spot where I use hyphens `--` between `Column` and `Active`. I tried wrapping `styles.Column--active` with backticks and it didn't work. Can someone please help to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be:

```
<div className={styles['Column--active']}>
```